# added a meta box to post however when saving menu while debug on throws a warning

Tags: custom-field, metabox, save-post

I've added several meta boxes to post and the function that suppose to save those boxes.

When i save menus ( appearance -> menu). it throws a warning for each added menu or sub menu `Notice: Undefined index: image_price_variation in /home1/xxx/public_html/xx/wp-content/plugins/xxx-shopping-cart/xxx_metabox_functions.php on line 89`

Although i am saving menus and not posts.

Here is a short version of the code:

```
function add_custom_meta_boxes() {  

/*  Adding price meta box to post   */
add_meta_box(  
    'oap_price_box',  
    'Product Price',  
    'oap_price_mockup',  
    'post',  
    'side',
    'high'
); 

// ... 
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_meta_boxes');

/* Prints the price  html mockup */
 function oap_price_mockup( $post ) {
wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'image_price_variation' );
$productPrice = (double)get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'productPrice', true );
$html  = '$ <input type="text" size="7" name="productPrice" placeholder="price" value="'.(($productPrice != '') ? $productPrice : '').'" />';    
echo $html;
}

function save_meta_boxes_post_data( $post ) {
    // verification
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
    return;

if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['image_price_variation'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) // - This is line 89 ..
    return;

if ( 'post' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post ) )
        return;
}

$post_ID = $_POST['post_ID'];

/*  Saveing Price*/
if(isset($_POST['productPrice']) && $_POST['productPrice'] != ''){
    $price = (double)sanitize_text_field( $_POST['productPrice'] );
    update_post_meta($post_ID, 'productPrice', $price);
}

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_meta_boxes_post_data' );
```

The error comes from the nonce field not being presented however doesn't WP separate between post saving to menu saving ? if so is there something i could do to change mine to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in your function to save the post meta data for the post type or better for $current_screen. The var is a global and return a object with different identifier to check, in which admin page init the function. Check in your function and return if is not the right $current_screen->id or post_type.

Small hint: use this [plugin](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/current-admin-info) for easy identify the var.

Also a example for check the current screen and if not the right, then return Null. The follow source is inside a function. But the var have more items inside the array, use the best for your requirement.

```
global $current_screen;

if ( isset( $current_screen->id ) && 
    'edit.php' === $current_screen->parent_file ) // check, if on edit post type page
 )
 return NULL;
```

Background: WordPress use the post type and his hooks also on other types, like attachments and nav menu.

Comment: I think i am already checking which post type it is. `if ( 'post' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post ) )
        return;
}` should i add else return ?

Comment: no, you check the data from the $_post, is always active, if the form tag send data.

Comment: I see. and how can i check for the current data then ?

Comment: [A example plugin](https://github.com/bueltge/Add-Language-Box/blob/master/fb-add-language-box.php), there add a meta box. See the structure on the `__construct()`. This makes it easy to control it. Also a small update on my answer with code for check the `$current_screen`.